# Passing data to another php file using GET method

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I know how to pass data to another page with Get method as hiperlink:

```
{echo "<a  href=file.php?variable1=".$row['value1']."&variable2=".$row['value2']."'>Confirm</a>"; }
```

How  add value from input field in this lane above? Is it possible?

```
<input name="field_name"  type="text" >
```

Comment: you search for a <form> or javascript to do this

Comment: <input name="field_name"  type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['variable1']; ?>" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
{echo "<a  href=file.php?variable1=".$row['value1']."&variable2=".$row['value2']."&field_name=".$_GET['field_name']."'>Confirm</a>"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case use `$_GET['field_name']` in your php code to add value of the input field

For eg:

```
<input name="field_name1"  type="text" >
<input name="field_name2"  type="text" >

{echo "<a  href=file.php?variable1=".$_GET['field_name1']."&variable2=".$_GET['field_name2']."'>Confirm</a>"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the value of the `method` attribute in your form, the input's value would be passed to PHP via either the `$_POST` or the `$_GET` array. You can link this to PHP via the following code:

```
{echo "<a  href=file.php?variable1=".$_GET['field_name']."&variable2=".$row['value2']."'>Confirm</a>"; }
```

Please note that the form should be **submitted** first before this code is executed. If this is not desirable, you should probably use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
{echo "<a  href=file.php?variable1=".$row['field_name']."&variable2=".$row['field_name_etc']."'>Confirm</a>"; }
```